# Problemas al Ejecutar Laravel 5.8 en hosting

Tags: laravel

Mantengo el siguiente error (extracto del error) en mi publicación en el hosting de producción

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--\\x0a\\x0a\\x0aErrorException: file_put_contents(C:\\x5claragon\\x5cwww\\x5ceSistema\\x5cstorage\\x5cframework/sessions/HEGnNmuUeKSgEo3cYMgqvKtWORVnkDFi0nz9U6mk): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in file /home/dinvagpc/ederthay/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 122\\x0aStack trace:\\x0a  1. ErrorException-&gt;() /home/dinvagpc/ederthay/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem...
```

Por lo expuesto no ejecuta la página, ya he buscado donde apunta al equipo pc de desarrollo y no encuentro este llamado al disco duro del pc y no a la ubicación en el hosting

Answer (score 0):

Tienes 2 opciones:
- El usuario de tu motor (seguramente www o www-data) no tiene permisos en esos archivos
- La ruta esta de los archivos esta mal o el document_root esta mal configurado